# Unable to require pry via Bundler.setup for a Ruby application that uses a Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile, pry

I'm writing a [simple ruby application](https://github.com/boddhisattva/learnings/tree/master/test_poro)(basically using PORO's). I've added a Gemfile to it and I'm trying to require the pry gem(which is useful for adding breakpoints while debugging, as the application grows) via the Gemfile but I'm unable to require that gem using `Bundler.setup`, things work fine with `Bundler.require`.

I'm trying to avoid the use of `Bundler.require` for reasons stated in [this blog](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/12/5-reasons-to-avoid-bundler-require) for instance.

In the [Employee.rb](https://github.com/boddhisattva/learnings/blob/master/test_poro/Employee.rb) file, I have the below code -

```
# require 'bundler'
# require 'bundler/setup'
# Bundler.setup(:default, :test, :development)

Bundler.require(:default, :development, :test)

def total_score(scores)
  binding.pry #added on purpose , just to see if the app stops at this breakpoint
  scores.inject(:+)
end
```

When I use Bundler.setup(uncommenting the lines commented above), instead of Bundler.require, I get the below error for the command `rspec spec .` given from my apps root directory-

```
 Failure/Error: expect(total_score(scores)).to eq(16)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x007fbda22b79d0>
 # ./Employee.rb:9:in `total_score'
 # ./spec/employee_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Also, just one more note, as per the [bundler docs](http://bundler.io/bundler_setup.html), I tried even doing a `require rubygems`, but even that doesn't help. Ideally, I would want to avoid using `require rubygems` for reasons mentioned in this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rubyinside.com%2Fwhy-using-require-rubygems-is-wrong-1478.html&ei=P6viVIa5DKK2mQXo8oCgDg&usg=AFQjCNHAA_k1vFzN4-2ukzJd8ugTHHC9iQ&sig2=UmNIpINECuDo_iZI92hPoA&bvm=bv.85970519,d.dGY).

How do I get my app to require the pry gem using Bundler.setup, without doing a `require rubygems` alongside and also without using `Bunder.require` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Bundler.setup` will simply add the gems to the load path, whereas `Bundler.require` will do both the adding to the load path and the require.

I recommend using `Bundler.setup` so that your code boots faster. Then when you need to require pry, do this:

```
require 'pry'
```

Comment: I think a caveat to this currently is, as the app grows, I will have to require each of those gems that I'd want to use if I want to avoid a `Bundler.require` , in this case would there be a value in adding a Gemfile to my app?

Comment: By having a Gemfile + Gemfile.lock, you can lock down to specific versions of the gems. If you don't have Gemfile + Gemfile.lock, different machines might run different Ruby versions.

Comment: Hmm, Thanks Ryan, just one more thing, I would want to limit the usage of `pry` or similar gems like `rspec` etc., to only dev and test environments. By doing a `require pry` and a similar thing for other gems, I think these gems wouldn't be limited to the environments to which I'd want to limit their usage , right ?